# Function with no (good) approximation?

Tags: approximation, computability

Does an (uncomputable) function $f(x)$ exist for which this statement is not true:

$$\forall\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}:\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)-F(x)| \mathrm{dx}<\varepsilon$$

Where $F(x)$ is any computable function.

Best regards

Kevin

Comment: It seems to me you're asking whether there exists an $f$ such that for some $\varepsilon$, the following integral is not less than $\varepsilon$ for all $F$, but your current statement currently doesn't say this very clearly.

Comment: What is computable function here?

Comment: you must put an absolute value to the integrand function..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are asking:

> Is there a function $f$ such that for *some* $\epsilon>0$, there is *no* computable $F$ with $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\vert f-F\vert dx<\epsilon$?

(If not, please clarify.)

Well, first of all, we need to be a bit careful. The notion of "computable function" makes perfect sense on $\mathbb{N}$, but things get a bit tricky when you want to define a computable function on $\mathbb{R}$. However, it turns out that the precise definition of "computable function on the reals" doesn't matter here: all we need is that there are only countably many of them.

Let $\{F_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ list the computable functions on reals, and let $f$ be defined as follows:

- $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$.
- For $x\in [i, i+1)$, we let $f(x)=F(x)+17$.

Then for every computable $F$, we will have $\int_\mathbb{R}\vert f-F\vert dx\ge 17$. Note that this uses nothing about the computable functions except for the fact that there are only countably many of them, so we can prove an identical result for larger classes of functions.

---

Note: The argument above uses "going off to infinity" in a crucial way. If I look instead at functions which are continuous, and live on the (compact) interval $[0, 1]$, then every such function *is* computably approximable: if $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a computable continuous $F:[0, 1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_{[0, 1]}\vert f-F\vert dx<\epsilon.$

Comment: Your last point reminds me of the theorem that a continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.  You only need that the set is bounded.  Although we can make nice bijections $(0,1) \leftrightarrow \Bbb R$ where intervals are maintained, the pieces on the left have to go to zero length while the pieces on the right do not.